# Looking for a phrase meaning “making unnecessary distinctions”

Tags: phrase-request

I’m looking for a phrase I once read from a philosophical composition, which roughly means “drawing a line between things that shouldn’t be distinguished from each other.” What I can vaguely recall is that its literal form involves parting the hair of something, maybe a tail.

Any clue is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Splitting hairs** (or **to split hairs**) is what you are looking for.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/split-hairs

Comment: That’s precisely what I was looking for. The original expression in the book consists of a proper noun with an initial ‘G,’ but I suppose that’s a variation. Many thanks!